# how to Display a Symbol from the .SWF file on Canvas?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, skinning

how i can display a symbol from the .`swf` on `canvas`.. i have exproted the .fla file from the flash CS3 as .swf file...

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do, do you want to embed the swf file inside a Canvas element, or you want to somehow extract one sybol from .swf file?

Comment: i want to extract one symbol from .swf and want to embed it in canvas.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, you would have to make a swf or an image or someting for each symbol you want to use, I just do not see a way to show only one symbol from a compiled swf file of multiple symbols...but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Embed(source='pathToSwf.swf', symbol="ExportForActionscriptSymbolName")]
private var MySwfSymbol:Class;
```

then you can add it to the stage like this:

```
var swfSymbol:MovieClip = new MySwfSymbol();
canvasId.addChild(swfSymbol);
```

HOWEVER,  this does not work if the symbol has only one frame.  In the event that it has only a single frame,  you will need to do this:

```
var swfSymbol:Sprite = new MySwfSymbol();
canvasId.addChild(swfSymbol);
```